# angular 8 Cordova plugin promise

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, promise, cordova-plugins

I am trying to return the data returned by the cordova plugin using a promise, but I don't know why the application closes. What is wrong with my code?

```
  scanQr() {
    this.qrscan.scanCode().then((imageData) => {
      console.log(imageData);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log("Camera issue: " + err);
    });
  }

 public scanCode(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan((result) => resolve(result), (error) => reject(error));
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just remove and add de cordova-android platform to lastest version (8.1.0) and is working.......